# Installed Bumblebee... how do I get Unity 3D running on Nvidia?

Tags: unity, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I installed Bumblebee following the instructions on the wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

It is working! I checked out `glxspheres` and then `optirun glxspheres`, and I got 55fps and 133fps respectively. *Hot*.

I also got the "Unity 3D" Ubuntu interface working after I installed Bumblebee. However, here's the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`:

```
adityamenon@jaguar:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 9.0.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

So it appears I'm still on the Intel card for my 3D-effects interface. I'm sure running on the nVidia card instead would make the experience faster... how do I do that?

This is my laptop: http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/NP300V5A-S0CIN-techspecs

Pertinent specs being:

```
Processor    Intel® Core™ i7 Processor2670QM (2.20GHz, 6MB L3 Cache)    
Graphic Processor    NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 520MX Graphics, Optimus™ technology
Main Chipset     Intel HM65
```

EDIT: Just read this question from the sidebar: [Can I set my Optimus Nvidia card to run Unity3D with bumblebee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87714/can-i-set-my-optimus-nvidia-card-to-run-unity3d-with-bumblebee)

I didn't think of `optirun /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`... so I did that, and here's the output:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 520MX/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.88

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  no
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

So unfortunately, it says Unity 3D isn't supported on this... the answers on the other question only advise selling this laptop and buying a new one with discrete graphics :D Is there any other way?

Comment: where are you on this issue ?  I have exact same question

Comment: Sorry, but this was pretty much a deadend.

Answer (score 1):

Install nvidia-prime, try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
sudo prime-select nvidia
```